# Shared wishlist email do not display images in gmail because of extra src attached

Tags: magento, gmail

I am able to see all the images in yahoo mail but in gmail images do not show up and upon inspecting I found this below extra code in the `src` of `<img>` tag:

```
<img src="/proxy/KVG425yi-NwYcvkLqXMswES3r4p-uwljwMd0X1M8J0pht9z1Kz5J5-ztkOZiGQpukKyVbRR-VHCrLJvPsTrDPSmOnOQxRU4uMDJXfpqRg26tXsHqDmgclC6kL8jpsZikPUKkj-OBCIxMRHaw0f4fobjLv79YY-EPV_O5UE39vuxiz5oXYlFj-f1IhCDEELiTDvaJi4kydxnlgD_Yg-NwMQ=s0-d-e1-ft MYIMAGEURL" />
```

Kindly do notice the long url before '`MYIMAGEWURL`', If I remove the code from `/proxy.... till -e1-ft` then images show up in gmail as well. But I am not sure whether is it google or my webserver which is attaching this extra bit of code. And how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

This is added by Google. They use proxy servers to check images for malware before inserting them into emails.

Comment: Why the images is not displaying? My current site is in http. It is due to that?